# how to use data from response section of post request in react js of django api call?

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

[this data i want to access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25Kkq.png)

this is my api call

```
api
  .post("/auth/registration/", data)
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    localStorage.removeItem("access");
    localStorage.removeItem("refresh");

    alert("Registration Successfull");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(Response.password1);
    alert(error.message);
    console.log(msg);
    localStorage.removeItem("access");
    localStorage.removeItem("refresh");
  });
```

i want to alert the message came from backend in responce section ,how do i do this

Comment: What have you tried? `res.email?.[0]`? Or is that the error you are showing us? Please share a more complete and comprehensive code example for what you're trying to do. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: When you're logging "res" can you show the object that is showing in the console. Also try logging "res.data" that should give you your response data

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the code in useEffect hook.